# jQuery uploadify: "complete" but nothing uploads

Tags: uploadify

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#file_upload').uploadify({
    'uploader'  : 'js/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
    'script'    : 'js/uploadify/uploadify.php',
    'cancelImg' : 'js/uploadify/uploadify-cancel.png',
    'folder'    : 'js/uploadify/uploads/',
    'auto'      : true
  });
});
</script>
```

This wont upload anything, all directories exists confirmed myself with it like 20 times..

When I try to put a / infront of the path: /js/uploadify.. it gives me 404 err.

It doesnt even ajax call uplodify.php ( when looking in the ajax net tab).

When the page loads, the one where this setting is and the input(where the upload is), it never stops "retrieves data from..", even when nothing is loading in the net tab. I also see it has executed and ran a ajaxrequest to /false which doesnt exists either..

help me! thinking about giving up on this jquery mod

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
'folder'    : 'js/uploadify/uploads/',
```

with:

```
'folder'    : 'js/uploadify/uploads',
```